# file upload using sharepoint web service

Tags: sharepoint

I have two files that need uploaded to two columns on a list (let say TestProcedure, UserGuide for example).  I also have other columns for other data.  I am able to add new data using sharepoint web service.  If I can get the two files uploaded at the same time the other data are being added, that would be great.  Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file, you need one requirement of these two requirements:

- either it's a Sharepoint List, and then the files will be attached (as an attachement) to the item,
- or it's a Sharepoint Documents Library, and the files are uploaded (one file = one item)

But you cannot upload a file into a column of a list... Eventually you can define an URL into a column/field to a file, but that's it.

Let's say you want to upload the two files from the user to a Documents Library and then set the URL to the files in your two columns of your list. You can do something like that:

- Look at [Local File to DataURI](http://aymkdn.github.io/FileToDataURI/) to create a box that permits to find the Base64 of the file selected locally by the user
- Then use [SharepointPlus `createFile()` function](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.html#.createFile) to upload the selected file to your Documents Library
- Store the URL of the uploaded file somewhere and let the user upload the second files (or hack the provided solution to make it possible to upload several files at once)
- When it's done use [SharepointPlus `add()` function](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.list.html#.add) to create a new item into your List with the stored URL of the two files for the TestProcedure and UserGuide columns

I hope it helps